# is it possible to enable jpeg, etc support for lamp after installation

Tags: linux, server, lamp

I am working on getting a script to work on a lamp server, it is a youtube like script it requires PHP5.6 (I know insecure). The server reports that almost everything is installed correctly with the exceptions of JPEG, LAME, XVID, THEORA, and FAAC support the only way I can find to enable these is to recompile with the libs all in a certain directory. I am looking for a way to circumvent the recompiling/reinstall, is it possible to do this?